# Best way to find nearest startDate and endDate according to target date

Tags: java

```
StartDate    EndDate
2008-03-10   2008-03-11
2008-03-10   2008-03-13
2008-03-11   2008-03-12
2008-03-15   2008-03-19
```

I want to find nearest one from date list according to target date **2008-03-12**

Output should be **StartDate = 2008-03-11 and EndDate = 2008-03-12**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is `LocalDate`, sort the list using natural sorting order which is ascending order

```
 List<LocalDate> d = Stream
            .of(LocalDate.parse("2008-03-10"), LocalDate.parse("2008-03-11"), LocalDate.parse("2008-03-12"),
                    LocalDate.parse("2008-03-13"), LocalDate.parse("2008-03-14"), LocalDate.parse("2008-03-19"),
                    LocalDate.parse("2008-03-15"), LocalDate.parse("2008-03-20"))
            .sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now find the index of `2008-03-12`

```
int index = d.indexOf(LocalDate.parse("2008-03-12"));
```

Then get the nearest previous date

```
 System.out.println("Previous nearest date : "+d.get(index-1));  //2008-03-11
```